# Improve React-Context structure

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm in the beginning of learning Reactjs and I am searching for some tips and tricks on how to improve following code structure (For now I'm only using sample data as values for the different states):

```js
import { useState, createContext } from "react"

export const UserContext = createContext()

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [uuid, setUuid] = useState("5498cdec-2bfb-455c-adc6-d59825adde71")
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("myEmail@email.com")
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("asdf1414")
    const [rank, setRank] = useState("ADMIN")
    const [profilePic, setProfilePic] = useState({ mime: "image/png", data: "" })
    const [joined, setJoined] = useState(Date.now())
    const [lastJoined, setLastJoined] = useState(Date.now())

    const value = {
        uuid: uuid,
        setUuid: setUuid,
        email: email,
        setEmail: setEmail,
        username: username,
        setUsername: setUsername,
        rank: rank,
        setRank: setRank,
        profilePic: profilePic,
        setProfilePic: setProfilePic,
        joined: joined,
        setJoined: setJoined,
        lastJoined: lastJoined,
        setLastJoined: setLastJoined
    }
    
    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

My **goal** with this context is as follows:
After successful log-in, all the data is fetched from the database and put into this context. Obviously I want to use and update the data from all over the webapp - therefore I provide the Context with the variable `value`.

My current "thorn in the eye" is, that the `value` variable is pretty stuffed and I have to manually type in all the data and update-functions. Is there a way I can simplify the `value` variable? Is there any best practice on how to do what I want to achieve?

Thanks in advance!

Kind Regards, Andreas

Comment: You can keep your entire user info in one state variable, which is the object that contains all of those properties. You can also use the `useReducer` hook, which lets you manage more complex states, or you can use one of the myriad tools for state mangament out there such as Redux, Mobx etc.

Comment: Thank you for the "kick-off" for me, to think different about my problem! I figured out a way to make this a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the kick-off to think different about my problem - I figured out a way to improve the code structure as follows:

```js
import { useState, createContext } from "react"

export const UserContext = createContext()

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const initValues = {
        uuid: "5498cdec-2bfb-455c-adc6-d59825adde71",
        email: "andreas.jokiel@hotmail.com",
        username: "asdf1414",
        rank: "ADMIN",
        profilePic: { mime: "image/png", data: "" },
        joined: Date.now(),
        last_joined: Date.now()
    }
    const [user, setUser] = useState(initValues)

    const changeUser = ([type, value]) => {
        setUser(prevValues => {
            return {...prevValues, [type]: value}
        })
    }

    const value = [user, changeUser]
    
    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

The code above basically initialises the user-state with the `initValues` object, as proposed from Ron B. In order to change values from the state the function `changeUser` takes in an array of `type` and `value` basically being the key and value for the value in the object you want to update and returning the new state with the spreaded old object and assigning the new value by the provided key.